# Nested Angular Apps - Is It Possible?

Tags: angular

I'm curious to know whether its possible to nest entire Angular applications inside one another.

Imagine I have `app1` and `app2` as two separate projects. I would want `app2` to be able to function on its own. By that I mean I'd want to be able to serve and build that project as a standalone app. However, I would also want to be able to nest `app1` inside of one of `app2`'s views.

Is this at all possible with the current Angular architecture as it exists today. I know the Angular team are working on the [Angular Elements](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1jiXHYwfe1iSUiVLdKLFhSPRHLI_FmIvrI60QTpP6KLk/edit#slide=id.g26d86d3325_0_0) project at the moment and I wonder if that would be suitable for this sort of thing.

Any thoughts from anyone that has attempted this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In this case most likely it would be easiest to have the app consistent of a shell, from which you can lazy load the modules for the two child apps. This will enable you to lazy load the modules (and routes) for the sibling applications. I work on an application that has 5 independent "applications" each that can load in our core then when the user goes to another application its lazy loaded into the core.

Comment: With Webpack as the build tool?

Comment: Yeah, I recently did some work with lazy loading modules via our routes. Might have to do the same thing here. Just thought there might be another way.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the idea is that app2 would be a library used in app1.

The simple way is to use nx extension. (https://nx.dev/angular) or create an angular library and move app2 to libray.

Another way is to have custom build process by npm build. You can use ng-packager to build a library for app1. In the same time, you can still use ng serve or npm run to test app2 in your local environment.

https://medium.com/self-learning/ng-packagr-

install ng-packagr

```
npm install ng-packagr --save-dev
```

create ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
  }
}
```

create src/public_api.ts

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "./src/public_api.ts"
  },  
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": ["."]
}
```

run ng-packagr to build app as library

```
node_modules\.bin\ng-packagr
```